# Horizontal histogram in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a horizontal histogram in gnuplot.

This is my current vertival (usual kind) histogram:

```
width=0.5
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0 
set boxwidth width*0.9
set style fill solid 0.5
plot "a" u (hist($2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc 3 notitle
```

Now what I need is the exact same result but rotated 90degrees clockwise.

I have tried this below but results are really not what I expect.

```
width=0.5
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0 
set boxwidth width*0.9
set style fill solid 0.5
plot "a" u (1.0):(hist($2,width)) smooth freq w boxes lc 3 notitle
```

Comment: See [Gnuplot interchanging Axes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898979/2604213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, this question is rather old and basically answered, let me give an update with an illustration, just for the records.

As far as I know, in current gnuplot (5.4.0) there is still no dedicated horizontal histogram style, probably because you can simply achieve it with `boxxyerror` (if you know how) as already mentioned in the answers of users @pygrac and @adhip agarwala and in the answer linked by @Christoph.
So, there is and was no need to create a vertical histogram and rotate it, because the plotting style `boxxyerror` existed already in gnuplot 4.0 (2004) or even earlier.

Since gnuplot 5.0.0 (2015) datablocks are available, so there is no need anymore to write the histogram data `smooth freq` into a file on disk.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### horizontal histogram
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 2000
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))+2):(1)   w table, \
         '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))-2):(0.5) w table
unset table

binwidth = 0.25
bin(x)   = binwidth * floor(x/binwidth)

set table $Histo
    plot $Data u (bin($1)):2 smooth freq
unset table

set style fill solid 0.5

plot $Histo u ($2/2):1:($2/2):(binwidth/2.) w boxxy ti "Horizontal Histogram"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While there is yet no generic support for horizontal plots in gnuplot, you can make quite decent horizontal barplots using the **boxxyerrorbars** style. It has a 6-column input (x, y, xlow, xhigh, ylow, yhigh). You just need to calculate the values for your bars yourself beforehand.

I just did something like this ($2 refers to 'center'):

> plot 'datafile.csv' using 'median':'center':'min':'max':($2-0.4):($2+0.4) with boxxyerrorbars

If you want category text-labels along the y-axis, here we go (I take them from the first column in my datafile):

> plot 'datafile.csv' using 'median':'center':'min':'max':($2-0.4):($2+0.4):ytic(1) with boxxyerrorbars

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. This works. Here is a consistent way doing the whole thing.
First print the usual output of the data file in a table format in another file say, datatable.txt

```
reset    
binwidth=0.015    
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0    
set table    
set output 'datatable.txt'    
plot './datafile.txt' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w p    
unset table

set output "horizontalhist.png"    
pl './datatable.txt' u 2:1:(0.0):2:(($1)-(binwidth/2.0)):(($1)+(binwidth/2.0)) w boxxyerrorbars
```

This should give you the horizontal histograms.

Answer (score 1):

If bitmap output is the sole concern, one can also employ the `convert` command of the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite after rendering the histogram with `gnuplot`.

```
convert -rotate 90 figure_in.png figure_out.png
```

Prior to doing this, rotate all labels within `gnuplot` with the `rotate` directive.

Examples and further details are provided [here](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/histogram.html).