# Gnuplot interchanging Axes

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to reproduce this plot with gnuplot:

[image]

My data has this format:

Data
1: time
2: price
3: volume

I tried this:

```
plot file using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 axes x1y2 with impulses
```

Which gives a normal time series chart with `y1` as price and `y2` as volume.
Next, I tried:

```
plot file using 2:1 with lines, '' using 2:3 axes x1y2 with impulses
```

Which gives prices series with `y1` as time and `y2` as volume.
However, I need the price to remain at `y1` and volume at `x2`.

Maybe something like:

```
plot file using 1:2 with lines,' ' using 2:3 axes y1x2 with impulses
```

However, that does not give what I want.

Comment: Does `plot 'file' using 2:1` do what you want? Otherwise, provide sample input file and more details about what you want.

Comment: Yes and it does in the 2nd command

Answer (score 3):

`Gnuplot` has no official way to draw this kind of horizontal boxplots. However, you can use the `boxxyerrorbars` (shorthand `boxxy`) to achieve this.

As I don't have any test data of your actual example, I generated a data file from a Gaussian random-walk. To generate the data run the following `python` script:

```
from numpy import zeros, savetxt, random

N = 500
g = zeros(N)
for i in range(1, N):
    g[i] = g[i-1] + random.normal()

savetxt('randomwalk.dat', g, delimiter='\t', fmt='%.3f')
```

As next thing, I do binning of the 'position data' (which in your case would be the volume data). For this one can use `smooth frequency`. This computes the sum of the `y` values for the same `x`-values. So first I use a proper binning function, which returns the same value for a certain range (`x` +- `binwidth/2`). The output data is saved in a file, because for the plotting we must exchange `x` and `y` value:

```
binwidth = 2
hist(x) = floor(x+0.5)/binwidth

set output "| head -n -2 > randomwalk.hist"
set table
plot 'randomwalk.dat' using (hist($1)):(1) smooth frequency
unset table
unset output
```

Normally one should be able to use `set table "randomwalk.hist"`, but due to a bug, one needs this workaround to filter out the last entry of the table output, see my answer to [Why does the 'set table' option in Gnuplot re-write the first entry in the last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353009/2604213).

Now the actual plotting part is:

```
unset key
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror

set xlabel 'time step'
set ylabel 'position value'
set x2label 'frequency'

set style fill solid 1.0 border lt -1

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'randwomwalk.png'

plot 'randomwalk.hist' using ($2/2.0):($1*binwidth):($2/2.0):(binwidth/2.0) with boxxy lc rgb '#00cc00' axes x2y1,\
     'randomwalk.dat' with lines lc rgb 'black'
```

which gives the result (with 4.6.3, depends of course on your random data):

[image]

So, for your data structure, the following script should work:

```
reset
binwidth = 2
hist(x) = floor(x+0.5)/binwidth
file = 'data.txt'
histfile = 'pricevolume.hist'

set table histfile
plot file using (hist($2)):($3) smooth unique
unset table

# get the number of records to skip the last one
stats histfile using 1 nooutput

unset key
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror

set xlabel 'time'
set ylabel 'price'
set x2label 'volume'

set style fill solid 1.0 border lt -1

plot histfile using ($2/2.0):($1*binwidth):($2/2.0):(binwidth/2.0) every ::::(STATS_records-2) with boxxy lc rgb '#00cc00' axes x2y1,\
     file with lines using 1:2 lc rgb 'black'
```

Note, that this time the skipping of the last `table` entry is done by counting all entries with the `stats` command, and skipping the last one with `every` (yes, `STATS_records-2` is correct, because the point numbering starts at `0`). This variant doesn't need any external tool.

I also use `smooth unique`, which computes the average value of the , instead of the sum (which is done with `smooth frequency`).