# changing the distance of y axis in histogram GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, histogram2d

I try to make this histogram with GNUPLOT but i can't understand how to show the names of the nations (i put also my dati.dat file).

Here the code:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo size 500,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output 'Err_rev.png'

# this command to modify the orientation of the png 
#convert -rotate 90 Err_rev.png Err_rev_out.png

set key at graph 0.24, 0.80 horizontal samplen 0.1
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.8
set xtic rotate by 90 scale 0
unset ytics
set y2tics rotate by 90
set yrange [0:100]; set xrange [*:*]
set y2label 'Paragone tra Nazioni: Domicilio - Hospice ' offset -2.5
set xlabel ' '
set size 1, 0.96
set label 1 'Nazioni' at graph 0.5, -0.1 centre rotate by 180
set label 2 'Domicilio' at graph 0.135, 0.83 left rotate by 90
set label 3 'Hospice' at graph 0.21, 0.83 left rotate by 90
p 'dati.dat' u 2 title ' ', '' u ($2/2.0+rand(0)/10.0) title ' ', '' u 0:(0):xticlabel(1) w l title ''
```

And here the file.dat:

```
Inghilterra 63 29
Belgio 71.6 9.9
Germania 66 14.8
Olanda 83.1 10.5
Portogallo 50.1 35.7
Spagna 60.1 16.8
Italia 76.1 12
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the xtic labels, you can use `using 2:xtic(1)` in the very first command. To see the labels properly you must set the alignment of the xtics to `right`.

And you can include the conversion command to rotate the plot inside the script. Call it with `system`. You must use `set output` without filename before that to indicate, that the file must be flushed and closed.

The changed script is:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo size 500,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output 'Err_rev.png'

set key at graph 0.24, 0.80 horizontal samplen 0.1
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.8
set xtic rotate by 90 scale 0 right
unset ytics
set y2tics center rotate by 90
set yrange [0:100]; set xrange [*:*]
set y2label 'Paragone tra Nazioni: Domicilio - Hospice ' offset -2.5
set size 1, 0.96
set label 1 'Nazioni' at graph 0.5, char 1 centre rotate by 180
set label 2 'Domicilio' at graph 0.135, 0.83 left rotate by 90
set label 3 'Hospice' at graph 0.21, 0.83 left rotate by 90

plot 'dati.dat' u 2:xtic(1) title ' ', '' u ($2/2.0+rand(0)/10.0) title ' '

set output
# this command to modify the orientation of the png 
system('convert -rotate 90 Err_rev.png Err_rev_out.png')
```

with the result `Err_rev_out.png` (with version 4.6.3):

[image]

An alternative way to plot horizontal histograms is with the `boxxyerrorbars` style, which also requires some, but other tricks. [Gnuplot interchanging Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898979/2604213)