# Gnuplot : Histogram - How do i swap x and y axis?

Tags: python, gnuplot, histogram

I have a data file with a number in every line and need to plot a histogram from that. My problem is that I need to swap the x and the y axis. 
Until now i used the following Code :

```
set style data histogram 

plot '4_2.dat' u 1
```

I read about 'set parametric', which did work for functions but I do not know how to use it for files. And I know that I normally can change the ordinate by using a different order in the using operator (u 1:2 / 2:1). Since I just got 1 entry per row, I do not know how to swap the x and y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot swap the axes for histograms, gnuplot implicitely uses integer x-values and you have no possiblity to changes this. As workaround you can use `boxxyerrobars`:

Consider the data file

```
first 5
second 11
third  2
fourth 6
```

You can plot this with

```
reset
set style fill solid noborder
set autoscale yfix
set offset 0,1,0.5,0.5
set xrange [0:*]
plot 'data.dat' using ($2*0.5):0:($2*0.5):(0.4):yticlabel(1) with boxxyerrorbars notitle
```

Of course you cannot make use of gnuplot's histogram features like stacking and grouping or automatic box calculations, but for simple histograms it works fine.

[image]
For another examples see [Gnuplot interchanging Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898979/2604213)