# Gnuplot rotate key

Tags: gnuplot

I made a horizontal histogram by turning the diagram by 270° using the rotate package in LaTex. 
It is no problem to adjust all the labels and tics, but I did not find a way to rotate the key.

[image]

Here is my gnuplot code:

```
set terminal epslatex  size 16cm, 32cm
set output "stackexchange.tex"
set xrange [-1:8]
set key
set boxwidth 0.95
set style data histograms
set style histogram errorbars
set style fill solid 0.8
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "#0080B0" lw 3
set yrange[600:1100]
unset ytics
set y2tics rotate
set y2label rotate "xyz / abc"
set xtics nomirror rotate scale 0 
plot 'stackexchange.dat' using 2:3:xticlabels(1) ls 1 title 'A', '' using 4:5 ls 1 fill pattern 6 title 'B'
```

That is how I implement it in LaTex:

```
\begin{figure}
        \begin{turn}{270}
        \resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{\input{stackexchange}}
        \end{turn}
\end{figure}
```

This is my datafile:

```
A     890.1  3.2  789.9 11.7 
B    626.97      20.467      862.8 12.3
C   923.9   5.89  963.8 3.7
D    785.233     15.921     627   2.3
E    903.167     7.94 880.9 1.9
F    863.43      25.237     778.2 4.2
G     909.6 5.370     941   13
H     895.633     40.401    813   11.3
```

Comment: http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.de/2009/10/turning-of-histogram.html does it the same way and has a hand-made legend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266452/horizontal-histogram-in-gnuplot

Comment: Thanks @Karl. This works, although I still hope for a simpler solution. The adjustment of the key and labels is tedious, especially in a multiplot graph

Comment: you could use "set label 'blabla'" together with "set object rectangle..."

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a classical [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Actually, you want to have a horizontal bar chart and since it doesn't exist as direct plotting style in gnuplot you think the solution would be to make a vertical bar chart and rotate it, and now you have the problem of how to rotate the key labels.

I know it would be convenient if there was a horizontal bar chart, but as far as I know gnuplot 5.4 still doesn't have it.
Actually, it's not really needed, because you can do it "manually" with the plotting style `boxxyerror` (available at least since gnuplot 4.0). The following script works with gnuplot>=5.0 (version at the time of OP's question) and with some small modifications even with older versions. The result below is from `wxt` terminal, but is should work the same with `epslatex` terminal.

The script is kept rather general. So, I added two columns to OP's data and simply by setting `N=3` you can have additional data in the graph (see second image).

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### Horizontal grouped bar chart
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A    890.1      3.2     789.9   11.7      627      2.3 
B    626.97    20.467   862.8   12.3      778.2    4.2
C    923.9      5.89    963.8    3.7      789.9   11.7
D    785.233   15.921   627      2.3      813     11.3
E    903.16     7.94    880.9    1.9      862.8   12.3
F    863.      25.237   778.2    4.2      880.9    1.9
G    909.6      5.37    941     13.0      941     13.0
H    895.6     40.41    813     11.3      963.8    3.7
EOD

N        = 2                              # number of boxes in group
gap      = 0.2                            # relative gap between groups
width    = 0.8                            # relative boxwidth in group
grid     = (1.0 - gap)/N                  # raster
y(i)     = column(0) + (i-N/2.-0.5)*grid  # y-position
dy       = grid*width/2.                  # half relative boxwidth 
title(i) = sprintf("column %d",2*i)       # key/legend entry

set style fill transparent solid 0.5 
set offset 0,0,0.5,0.5
set xrange [600:1100]
set yrange [:] reverse
set ytics out
set key noautotitle

plot for[i=1:N] $Data u (0):0:(0):i*2:(y(i)-dy):(y(i)+dy):ytic(1) w boxxy lc i ti title(i), \
     for[i=1:N]    '' u i*2:(y(i)):i*2+1 w xerr lc i
### end of script
```

**Result:**

`N = 2`

[image]

`N = 3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do something like this :

```
x = 0.5
y = 1000
dx = 0.1
dy = 50
set label 'B' at x,y rotate by 90 offset 0.5,-1
set style rectangle fc ls 3 fs pattern 6 border 3 
set object rectangle from x,y to x+dx,y+dy
```

I let you set the properties of the `style rectangle` so it matches your histogram.